# Karate - Starting Mock Server with multiple feature files

Tags: karate

My feature files are structured like this

[image]

As you can see, each module has a common, mock and test feature files.
for eg: `category-common.feature`, `category-mock.feature` and `category-test.feature`. These contain all common definitions, mock API definitions and tests respectively related to category APIs.

We are using the `java -jar karate.jar -m <feature_file>` command to run the mock server.
This approach is good when we are testing the APIs module wise. The question is how can we deploy all mocks together in a single port?

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61373657/karate-standalone-as-mock-server-with-multiple-feature-files) answer, it is not possible to do it. If not, what are some other approaches we can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone contributed a PR to add this post the 1.0 release, so you should read this thread: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1566

And you should be able to test and provide feedback on 1.1.0.RC2

Of course if you can contribute code, nothing like it :)

Comment: thanks! was able to run with the following command
java -jar D:\karate-1.0.1\karate-1.1.0.RC2.jar -m manufacturer-mock.feature -m payment-mock.feature

the server is running, but there seems to be some issues with schema checks. Debugging that...